# how can I get hostname and put it on cfg

Tags: ansible

how can I edit a remote cfg file or in my case

I must modify the "hostname" by the name of the remote machine,

knowing that it is for automated because aprre I will deploy it on +300 server

I must be able to get the remote hostname and put it in the cfg file with ansible

thanks

```
############# file for config host ############
---
- hosts: computer_user
  remote_user: toto
  tasks:
  - name: "config zabbix agent"
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/zabbix.cfg
      regexp: '(.*)hostname_local(.*)'
      line: '%hostname%'


########### file_cfg_on_computer_user #########

hostname_local: here_i_want_put_the_hostname_of_my_computer_user_with_a_like_%hostname%
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible defines many [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) at runtime.

You can use `{{ inventory_hostname }}` to returns the inventory name for the ‘current’ host being iterated over in the play.

Or you can execute a remote command and use result in next task :

```
---
- hosts: computer_user
  remote_user: toto
  tasks:
  - name: "get hostname from remote host"
    shell: hostname
    register: result_hostname
  - name: "config zabbix agent"
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/zabbix.cfg
      regexp: '(.*)hostname_local(.*)'
      line: '{{ result_hostname.stdout }}'
```

Comment: it works but I would like to get information directly from the machine itself, for example an uptime or something else,

I am that the ansible command -m setup "hostname" gives us all the information but how to have all that in a .yml

example

```
---
- hosts: computer_user
  remote_user: foo
  tasks:
```
 - name: "get info from remote host"
   shell: ansible -m setup "remote host"
  
- name: "config zabbix agent"
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/zabbix.cfg
      regexp: '(. *) hostname_local (. *)'
      line: '{{var_from_ansible_-m setup"remote host}'
```
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you really want, but if you want to get the hostname of the system where your playbook is running, then you have two possibility :

1. You can get the value of `inventory_hostname` : It is the name of the hostname as configured in Ansible’s inventory host file
2. Or you can get the value of the ansible fact `ansible_hostname` : this one is discovered during the *gathering fact* phase

You can find more info about hosts variables and facts [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables)